# Best way to create navigation in a single page

Tags: aurelia

I would to create a navigation module for navigate between the different section of my single page app but I don't find any elegant solution.

Do I need to use the route component ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial on that topic:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/aurelia/aurelia_routing.htm

But shortly, it works like this:

**Step 1: Create subviews**

*subview.html*

```
<template>
  <h1>Subview</h1>
</template>
```

*subview.js*

```
export class Subview {}
```

**Step 2: Configure parent view**

Add `<router-view>` to parent's `html` file

*app.html*

```
<template>
  <router-view></router-view>
</template>
```

Configure `Router` in parent's viewmodel

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  config.map([
    { route: ['', 'home'], name: 'subview', moduleId: './subview', nav: false, title: 'Subview' },
  ]);
  this._router = router;
}
```

Now you can see the `subview`'s contents put into the `<router-view>` whenever you are on the route `/#/` or `/#/home`.

You can navigate between the views by adding a `route-href="route-name"` parameter to anchor tags. Or by calling the function from the `this._router` object directly, for example: `this._router.navigateToRoute('route-name');`.

Comment: Sections would probably go inside the subview. And then, if necessary, use a child router.

Comment: In my case all sections are displayed on the same view and what I want is to navigate between sections inside this view like anchor in html.